# Loading image with same name via jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, caching

i need to replace the uploaded image with the previous image with same name and size and after sucessfull upload refresh the div to show the new image .everything is working fine except that the new image is not updated on ajax load method i have to refresh the whole page to do so.

hare is related code

```
var options = {
        target:   '#imager778',   // target element(s) to be updated with server response 
        beforeSubmit:  beforeSubmit,  // pre-submit callback 
        success:       afterSuccess,  // post-submit callback 
        resetForm: true        // reset the form after successful submit 
    };  
     $('#MyUploadForm').submit(function() { 
        $(this).ajaxSubmit(options);            
        // always return false to prevent standard browser submit and page navigation 
        return false; 
    });
    function afterSuccess()
   {
    $('#submit-btn').show(); //hide submit button
    $('#loading-img').hide(); //hide submit button
    $("#divofimage").load("page.php #divofimage");
    }
```

can any one suggest me anything
i think ths is because of caching
 i have already tried ading random numbers to the url but no effect

Comment: You should add random string to new image url, something like `url + '?r=' + Math.random()`

Comment: already tried but no effect

Comment: what is response from page.php?

Comment: on refreshing the page the image gets updated to it. but not on ajax load the image is going to database and to the server

Comment: no, i mean, page.php serving raw image or `<img src="url">` ?

Comment: the page is showing this <img src="uploads/picture.jpg"/> 
everytime the new picture uploaded is renamed to picture.jpg and replaces the previous one

Comment: that's your problem, you should modify image url with random string, not page.php url, so your page.php should return `<img src="uploads/picture.jpg?r=<?=random()?>"/>`

Answer (score 1):

We can break the cache of browser by forcing the image through ajax and then associating the new image with the timestamp .

```
var name='FULL_PATH?dt=' + (+new Date());
$('<img src="'+name+'">').load(function() {
       $('#ID').html('');
       $(this).width('40').height('40').appendTo('#ID');
});
```

and you have got the nice and cool new image :)